# Isn't it against the rules to get Stack Overflow Privileges before reaching needed reputation?

Tags: support

According to help center, a user need a at least 1,000 reputation to view vote counts, but there is an extensions called [“View Vote totals” without 1000 rep](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep)
to get that privileges before earning 1,000 reputation.

It is surprised that it is promoted via Stackapps which is a Stack Exchange family site. So, isn't it against the rules to get Stack Overflow  Privileges before reaching needed reputation?

Comment: Too many down-votes within a few seconds, Is this a low quality support question?

Comment: I'd imagine if it wasn't allowed they'd remove it from Stackapps?

Comment: It's really hard to do anything illegal here on SO.

Comment: @DavyM That's not true, plagiarism is copyright infringement and thus illegal and is relatively common on SO.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I put that as a challenge because I knew people couldn't resist the urge to correct a statement like that, but... I was kind of hoping for something more entertaining than just plagiarism ;D

Comment: @DavyM I like the malware development related questions that are for educational purposes :)

Comment: It's not like that privilege really gives you any power. You just know more about a certain post. Like Erik said, it's only locked behind 1k rep in the first place because it impacts performance, not because it's something that should be entrusted. I also think "illegal" is a bit of a strong term for this. The most it could be is against the terms, which won't get you arrested.

Comment: @DavyM Chinese political dissidents have come to SE to post content the government doesn't approve of, which is illegal there.  Is that more entertaining?

Comment: If it's against the rules to get privileges regardless of rep we need to jail all the mods, they get all privileges regardless of rep, as do some employees.

Comment: Servy, you never disappoint.

Answer (score 18):

No, this is not illegal. No-one will call the police on you and arrest you.

Also, moderators likely won't mind.

The main reason this is hidden by default and for users below that rep threshold is because looking it up causes a considerable load on the server ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69854/369403)). But if you go out of your way to install an extension to look it up or write a SEDE query, I'm sure no-one will mind.

Comment: The actual difference in performance ought to be really noticable: getting the simple score of a post is 1 clustered index seek on `posts` while getting the detailed score is 2 conditional aggregates on `votes`

Comment: @Magisch They should be able to calculate up- and downvotes based on the amount of votes and score in the application layer. That should be a bit faster

Comment: '*But officer, I was assured the police wouldn't be called...*'

Answer (score 9):

It's on the [app description](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep), my emphasis:

> This script is written in JavaScript and a bit of jQuery. ***It depends on the Stack Exchange API*** (v2, JSONP).

And checking [its code](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/6192-stack-exchange-view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep/code):

```
var api_url = location.protocol + '//api.stackexchange.com/2.0/posts/';
```

Hardly anything illegal using Stack Exchange tools to deal with Stack Exchange sites.

Going a bit further, I can't find any restriction to this kind of use inside [Stack Exchange, Inc. API Terms of Use](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/api-terms-of-use) or [Stack Exchange Network Acceptable Use Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy).